# Unit test for network answer

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, testing

In my app I use network calls to get `JSON` answer. I would like to make some test for these calls, but I only find test with `MockUp`.

But my purpose is to test if my app can handle `JSON` change from the API, so make mockup json isn't valable for my case.

Is it possible to make real api call in `Android Test` ? It's possible on `Swift` with `iOS`, there is any equivalent ?

Earlier, I've tried to make a `bash script` which call api and put answer in a `JSON file` and then run test with the file, but I feel that my solution wasn't a good thing.

Thank all for yours answers, have a nice day !

Comment: I don't understand. your problem is to make jsons for testing?

Comment: @mohsen I get json from a web api, I want to call that api to get json in my test, but I don't want to use mockup to check behavior if the api return wrong json

Comment: you don't need to call the actual API for a test. you should just mock the API response

Comment: @mohsen but if the API change his response, how can I see my app behavior ?

Comment: you just have to mock that change too